# Spring Boot - log4j2.properties creating log files but not writing the logs in file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, log4j2

I have used log4j2.properties file with springboot application. Log file was creating but logs are not written into the file.

Please find the details as below:

## log4j2.properties

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = C:/Logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/app.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.java.app //Parent Package name for the application 
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

## POM.XML

```
<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

## DemoApplication.java

```
package com.java.app;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

      private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.info("Logger enabled: Entering main \\n\\n");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        log.info("**** Demo Application Started *****");

      }

    }
```

Logs are appearing in the console but not written into file as i am not getting the issue.

It's strange, parent package logger "Logger enabled: Entering main \n\n" is written into the file and the other parent logger "**** Demo Application Started *****" is not written into the file as the code is shown above. and also checked for the sub package i.e `com.java.app.endpoint` loggers even those also not written into the file.

and also identified that the console log is coming like as

2018-08-03 12:55:18.302  INFO 11440 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] c.j.c.e.Classname : logger message

If c.j.c.e. coming as prefix to the class name in logs those are not written into the file why?

I might be doing something wrong. Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Can you try to configure using log4j2-spring.xml as Spring Doc's recommend? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: Our Requirement is to develop logging using properties file so trying.as following based on this `https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/` . i couldn't find exactly what is the issue here. Thanks @ Jose A. Matarán

Comment: Did you try to change name of log to a name without path?

Comment: is `property.filename = C:/Logs this?` @Jose A. Matarán

Comment: put property.filename = logs

Comment: It's strange, this `Logger enabled: Entering main \\n\\n` writing into the files but below one as `**** Demo Application Started *****` not and checked for sub package logger even that also not written into file. Thanks @Jose A. Matarán

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177282/discussion-between-rajeswari-reddy-and-jose-a-mataran).

Comment: Please look into this. Thanks. @Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 11):

I also face with this problem following the tutorial on springframework.guru. After searching on spring boot docs then I config my pom.xml with those dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and add 
`logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2.properties` in the application.properties file. After that I can see the log appear on my log file when I run the application.

Comment: Weard: Without the `logging.config` property, the file seems to not be loaded correctly (I say correctly, because the log file is created but the logs are not written in it)

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring Boot you can specify `log4j2.properties` inside the `application.properties`

```
logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2.properties
```

Comment: No, It's not working even added above in application.properties and i have seen some blogs that if we are using 2.4 greater version of  log4j2 then mapping also not required. if the filename is log4j2.properties then it will automatically picks up and execute. Thanks @Ashraf Sarhan

Comment: Better logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml

Answer (score 2):

Change the POM.xml file as below and it should be working.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>

        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Please note that, Recommendation is to use log4j2.xml instead of log4j2.properties.

Answer (score 0):

it also seems to be necessary to set log4j as standard apache logging. In general it uses logback. So I had to add

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
     <exclusions> 
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId> 
       </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
```

to my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot supports [Log4j 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x) for logging configuration, you can get how to configure from [Configure Log4j for Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging)

First you need to exclude spring boot logging

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then have `log4j2.json` or `log4j2.xml` or `log4j2.yaml` in your `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0):

To use the external configurations, you can simply place *log4j.properties* or *logback-spring.xml* or *logback.xml* and add the following property to your *application.properties* file

`logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml`