# Logger issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have implemented Logging in Spring Boot application  by using `log4j2.properties` file.

Please find the code as in below reference url:

[Spring Boot - log4j2.properties creating log files but not writing the logs in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649986/spring-boot-log4j2-properties-creating-log-files-but-not-writing-the-logs-in-f?noredirect=1#comment90270216_51649986)

The console logging is working and also file creating and one of the log is writing into the file but others are not writing into the file.

Please find the differences of loggers as printing in console as below:

```
[INFO ] 2018-08-06 11:48:05.609 [restartedMain] DemoApplication                  - Logger enabled: Entering main //this log is writing into file.

2018-08-06 11:48:14.211  INFO 10788 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.c.DemoApplication                  : **** Demo Application Started *****// this is not writing into file.
```

but for both using  log.info to print the loggers.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: In reference url following package is configured for file logger: com.java.app, but in  your example the package seems to be different one. Have you edited your log4j.properties with correct package name?

Comment: no, I am using the same package, but in that demoapplication class having 2 loggers one is above of `SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);` and another one is below of above statement. but the loggers printing in console with some difference as shown in above. and also one logger is writing into file and another is not writing into file. now i have updated package info as well in reference url. Please check and help me on this. Thanks @ Andrei Prakhov

Answer (score 1):

You have to carefully check your log4j2.properties file. I have tested with your example and following configuration works just fine:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=demo.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.testsexample.test5
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Main class is the following (package name should correspond logger.file.name property in log4j2.properties):

```
package com.testsexample.test5;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test5Application {

    private final static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Test5Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOG.info("Logger enabled: Entering main \n\n");
        SpringApplication.run(Test5Application.class, args);
        LOG.info("**** Demo Application Started *****");
    }
}
```

Project structure is:

[image]

Strange, but I have reproduced your issue after several relaunches. Please try to replace log4j2.properties with following log4j2.xml - the problem was gone with xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="demo.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

For daily rolling appender it will be:

```
<RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="demo.log" filePattern="demo %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy></DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```

Comment: Still getting `CteappApplication - Logger enabled: Entering main` only not getting the other logger as in below of this `SpringApplication.run(Test5Application.class, args);`. did you see this `**** Demo Application Started *****` in your logs? Thanks. @Andrei Prakhov

Comment: After several relaunches I am also missing **** Demo Application Started *****, that's strange. After replacing configuration with xml one, logging works fine again.

Comment: Yes, with logj2.xml is working fine but we need daily rolling appender. Is it possible with log4j2.xml ? Thanks. @Andrei Prakhov

Comment: Yes it is possible, you just need different appender type for that (see edited post above)

Comment: Shall i add this into above appenders or shall i replace with above file appender? 
 and when i pointing to local directory to make log file as "C:\\Logs" and its not working.Thanks @Andrei Prakhov

Comment: Yes, just replace old file appender <File> with rolling file appender <RollingFile>. Following file place change works fine for me (make sure that your user has permissions to write to desired folder): <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="C:\\Logs\demo.log" filePattern="demo %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177478/discussion-between-rajeswari-reddy-and-andrei-prakhov).

Comment: how to set back up files size to 10 using rollingappender. thanks @Andrei Prakhov

Comment: You need to add SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy then <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>